# HTML simple anchor link doesn't work in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: html, css, anchor

I'm making a portfolio page here (`http://198.96.94.51/v2/`) and while clicking on the `navigationMenu` links on the side really fast, they don't seem to redirect to the proper anchor (some of them don't move the page at all). I've initialized my anchor tags like this

```
<ol class="curtains">
    <li id="home" class="cover">
        <a id="home"></a>
        <header data-fade="550" data-slow-scroll="3">
            <h1>John Smith</h1>
            <h2>HOBBY/JOB TITLE</h2>
        </header>
    </li>
</ol>
```

My navbar code -

```
<ul id="navigationMenu">
    <li>
        <a class="home" href="#home">
            <span>Home</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="about" href="#about">
            <span>About</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
         <a class="projects" href="#projects">
            <span>Projects</span>
         </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="resume" href="#resume">
            <span>Resume</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="contact" href="#contact">
            <span>Contact us</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But just clicking on the navbar, or even typing #home into the address bar won't bring the browser back to the top sometimes. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: where is href attribute in a tag ?

Comment: Added navbar information

Answer (score 3):

Ids identify anchor points so they must be unique.

But if you just want to go to the top of the page you should try a simple `#` as value for your href attribute.

A link to the id of e.g. a `<div>` tag would lead you to this `<div>` tag.

```
<a href="#anchor"></a>

<div id="anchor"></div>
```

this fiddle shows you: http://jsfiddle.net/aYGFR/1/

Comment: For the noobs out there, it's id="anchor" not id="#anchor" (not easy to spot once the mistake is made.)

Answer (score 0):

You can give like this:  `<a id="home" href="home.php">Home</a>`