# onClick and href conflict in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, onclick

I tried implementing an HTML anchor with the following:

```
<a href="#some-id" onClick="showDiv(event)">
```

The code of `showDiv()`:

```
function showDiv(e) {
    jQuery("#container").show(1500);
}
```

Inside `#container` there is a child node with id `some-id`.

The function `showDiv()` shows a particular hidden element containing a child with id `some-id`. The intention is to make this anchor a button, and when users click it it shows the element and directs the user to the child with the id. This works fine in Chrome, however in Firefox it will show the element but the redirection will not work. Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: Please show your full code.

Comment: Are there multiple instances of the same ID occurring in your document?

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann code added.

Comment: @Terry Thanks, the id is unique, since if the container is not hidden, it redirects normally.

Comment: My guess would be that Firefox doesn’t jump to the element, because it is hidden using `display:none` at the time where that jump is supposed to occur.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question here
[HTML simple anchor link doesn't work in Chrome/Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938762/html-simple-anchor-link-doesnt-work-in-chrome-firefox)
I think its an anchor issue where firefox doesn't think they are unique.

Comment: Thank you, but the id is unique and it directs correctly when the parent element is not hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative. Assuming this markup:

```
<a id="trigger">Click me</a>

<div id="container">
    <a id="some-id">Hello</a>
</div>
```

You could do it like this:

```
function showDiv() {
        jQuery("#container").show(1500, 'swing', function(){ 
              jQuery('#some-id').focus();
       });
}
jQuery(function() {
     jQuery('#trigger').on('click', showDiv);
});
```

I've moved the click handler out of the markup and made a strict distinction between the two stages of the process targeting the `some-id` element in a callback from the original `show` call.

Comment: Thank you! But the problem is I am currently using Metronic 3.6.2, which for some reason makes this way of method binding non functional. Also I was trying to come up with a more generic method, since there are a lot of different elements in the container that I wish the page can redirect to.